# populating fullcalendar using SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, fullcalendar

I have seen several questions around this topic on here, but can't seem to get my fullcalendar to display properly using the provided methods, so I was hoping someone could give me a hand with fixing my issue.

My JSON feed seems to populate correctly, although I see some saying that it only works with single quote, and others only work with double quotes.  (possibly an issue with the double quotes surrounding the whole feed?)

```
"[{"title":"change1","start":"2016-10-17T10:00:00","end":"2016-10-17T12:00:00","allDay":false},{"title":"change2","start":"2016-10-18T10:00:00","end":"2016-10-18T12:00:00","allDay":true},{"title":"change3","start":"2016-10-19T10:00:00","end":"2016-10-19T12:00:00","allDay":false}]"
```

calendar.aspx.cs:

```
public class Event
        {
            public string title;
            public string start;
            public string end;
            public bool allDay;
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetEvents()
        {
            var events = new List<Event>();
            var sqlQuery = "SELECT title, starttime, endtime, allDay FROM [DeploymentDashboard].[dbo].[ChangeCalendar]";

            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=*server*;Initial Catalog=DeploymentDashboard;Integrated Security=True;"))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                events.Add(new Event()
                                {
                                    start = DateTime.Parse(reader["starttime"].ToString()).ToString("s"),
                                    end = DateTime.Parse(reader["endtime"].ToString()).ToString("s"),
                                    title = reader["title"].ToString(),
                                    allDay = (bool)reader["allDay"]
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    sqlConnection.Close();
                }
            }

        var theSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return theSerializer.Serialize(events);
    }
```

calendar.aspx:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "calendar.aspx/GetEvents", 
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#calendar2').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                events: data.d
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: The calendar will display, but no entries.  I am not sure what is causing the entries to be blank.  No errors - just not populating from the JSON feed.

Comment: okay so what calendar control are you using ? meaning is it asp.net or Jquery UI and or telerik control? - am asking cause your code behind (C#) seems to return the data in the expected format, binding the recieved data to the control seems to be the issue, so one needs to know what type of control is used here?

Comment: Sorry, it is asp.net.

Comment: <div class="ibox-content">
     <div id="calendar2"></div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var eventsArray = [{"title":"change1","start":"2016-10-17T10:00:00","end":"2016-10-17T12:00:00","allDay":false},{"title":"change2","start":"2016-10-18T10:00:00","end":"2016-10-18T12:00:00","allDay":true},{"title":"change3","start":"2016-10-19T10:00:00","end":"2016-10-19T12:00:00","allDay":false}]

$('#calendar2').fullCalendar({
  events: eventsArray
});
```

Comment: Yes, that works.  Which leads me to believe that the quotes enclosing the feed is causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, because you must pass an array to te fullcalendar events. With the quotes it probably will be treated like a string

Comment: @slarimore I have the same issue you were having.. what did you do to fix?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it.

```
events: JSON.parse(data.d);
```

This helped: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

> Imagine we received this text from a web server:
>
> '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'
>
> Use the JavaScript function JSON.parse() to convert text into a
>   JavaScript object:
>
> var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');